# Connection failed when trying to request an API, only when deploying into production on Ionos/1&1 Hosting

Tags: c#, hosting

I am creating a small web api in C#/.NET, which as some point have to request some data from an external API.
When I am testing in local, on my machine, it is working perfectly.

But when It is deployed on distant web hosting (I am using Ionos/1&1 Web Windows Hosting solution), for testing my app, I get this error message from my own API:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond {ip}

Here is the code calling the API and getting the response

```
        Uri myUri = new Uri("url", UriKind.Absolute);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUri);
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelOfResult>(result);
            }
        }
```

Is it a proxy issues ? Code issues ? Hosting issues ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to the support from Ionos, I manage to get a proxy to make it works, by adding this code

```
request.Proxy = new WebProxy({proxy}, {proxy_port});
```

If you have any issue, please try the solution of TheGunners, or ask for your provider to give you the proxy

Still a shame I have to ask for it, but hey, it is working now

Answer (score 2):

It seems it is proxy issue. Please try to add this code on your web.config:

```
 <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="false" >
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```